# Inserir item selecionado do SPINNER no SQLITE

Tags: java, android

Como identificar o item selecionado no SPINNER e inseri-lo no banco de dados SQLITE.

Eu consigo fazer o insert no Sqlite usando o dados fornecidos no EditText, porem não estou conseguindo criar uma forma de fazer algo semelhante com o SPINNER.

Código:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recadastramento);

    marca = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_marca);
    modelo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_modelo);
    constante = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_constante);
    data_fabricacao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_fabricacao);
    salvar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_salvar);

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    AddData();

    spiner_constante = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_constante);
    spiner_constante.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    loadSpinnerData();

    private void loadSpinnerData() {
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

    List<Integer> constante = db.GetAllConstante();

    ArrayAdapter<Integer> dataAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<Integer> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,constante);

    spiner_constante.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);
    dataAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
}


public void AddData() { // AQUI É FEITO O INSERT DOS DADOS DOS EDITTEXT, NO SQLITE

    salvar.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(marca.getText().toString(), modelo.getText().toString(), constante.getText().toString(), data_fabricacao.getText().toString());


}
```

}

Comment: Para obter o item selecionado do *Spinner* basta utilizar `spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()`. Não entendi muito bem o seu código para poder indicar onde colocar este trecho. Se puder explicar melhor.

Comment: Então @Paulo Rodrigues, apos fazer o load no spinner, eu tenho um botao instanciado com o setOnClicllistener para fazer o insert no sqlite.

    `myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    public void AddData() {
    salvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Overridepublic void onClick(View v) {
            boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma vez que você tem a lista de itens do *Spinner* com este trecho de código:

```
List<Integer> constante = db.GetAllConstante();
```

Basta você utilizá-lo para obter qual é o item selecionado:

```
constante.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition())
```

E então, este valor ser inserido no banco de dados, junto com seus outros valores. Isso descarta a utilização do `OnItemSelectedListener`, já que a sua intenção não é realizar esta ação ao selecionar um item do *Spinner* e sim no botão *Salvar* (a menos que você esteja utilizando para outra ação).

Comment: Implementei os codigo acima, e o insert funcionou, porem ele inseriu todos os dados do spinner mesmo eu tendo utilizado o getSelectedItemPosition.


List<String> mod = myDb.GetAllModelos();
                        mod.get(spiner_modelos.getSelectedItemPosition());
myDb.insertData(mod.toString());

Comment: Não é `mod.toString()` que você deve inserir, já que `mod` e a sua *lista* inteira. Você tem que inserir o `mod.get(spiner_modelos.getSelectedItemPosition())`.

Comment: Deu certo,  
String rec= mod.get(spiner_modedlos.getSelectedItemPosition());
myDb.insertData(rec.toString());

Vlw !

Answer (score 1):

Faltou você copiar o método que tivesse que implementar, *onItemSelected*.

Você deve implementar o seguinte neste método:

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Ele irá retornar o objeto selecionado no Spinner conforme o tipo que você utilizou para preencher o ArrayAdapter, no seu caso.
        objeto = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        // Após pegar o objeto selecionado é só fazer a inserção na base de dados
        myDb.insertData(objeto);
    }
```

Espero ter ajudado!
Boa sorte!

Comment: implementei o metodo, e foi possivel fazer o insert no sqlite, porem ele salvou o seguinte dado no sqlite :  

android.widget.Spinner{3088dda1 VFED..C. ........ 245,270-688,343 #7f080050 app:id/sp_marca}                                   

`public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View   view, int position, long id) {

String objeto = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()

myDb.insertData(objeto.toString());`